# React-leaflet: Change marker opacity on mouse event

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to change marker opacity on `mouseover` event.

```
<Marker position={} icon={} opacity={0.7}
    eventHandlers={{
        mouseover: (event) => {
            // change opacity here?
            // I tried:
            event.target.options.opacity = 1;
        }
    }}
/>
```

That doesn't work. I am thinking the only way to do it is to hold a state for every marker, but I don't like that idea. This is just a simple task and I don't want to hold all states for this.

EDIT:

This is a method I call in render() inside the `MapContainer` tag.

```
const parseObjects = () => {
    let markers = [];
    Object.values(nodes).map( (node) => {
        const marker = useRef(null);
        markers.push(
            <Marker position={node.getPosition()}
                ref={marker}
                key={marker.id}
                ...>
                     // pop up and tooltip
            </Marker>
        );
    });

    // More objects being parsed... 
    
    return markers;
}

return (
    <MapContainer>
        {parseObjects()}
    </MapContainer>
)
```

I turned it into this:

```
return (
    <MapContainer>
        Object.values(nodes).map( (node) => {
            const marker = useRef(null);
            return <Marker position={node.getPosition()}
                ref={marker}
                key={marker.id}
                ...>
                     // pop up and tooltip
                </Marker>
            );
        });
    </MapContainer>
)
```

Both of these examples give me

> React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```js
<>
  {markers.map(marker => {

    // reference - no need for array
    const marker = useRef(null);

    return (
      <Marker
        ref={marker}
        key={marker.id}
        position={[marker.lat, marker.lng]}
        eventHandlers={{
          mouseover: () => (marker.current._icon.style['opacity'] = 0.5),
          mouseout: () => (marker.current._icon.style['opacity'] = 1),
        }}
      >
      </Marker>
    );
  })}
</>
```

it uses a `ref` to get a handle on the HTML element and changes styles directly on it.

Comment: That works for ONE marker. But I would have to hold a reference to each marker I put on the map. Which means I would need an array of useRef() and that just seems too compliated for something so simple.

Comment: @kristyna: does the extended example work for your use case?

Comment: This one says "React Hook "useRef" cannot be called inside a callback."

Comment: hmm, is that some form of eslint warning? I don't get any such error/ warning...

Comment: I edited the question with more code. I call that code inside the render function. Maybe the problem is that I am saving the code in a variable? I just started React recently, so I am not exactly sure with how exactly does ref work.

Comment: can you try extracting the code from the function and running it inline within the `render` function itself - I think there is no need to push it to an array and return that array - try like I showed in my example within the `{...}`. 



As a general rule: you shouldn't define functions within the `render` function

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly, but I posted again what I did. It did not change the outcome though. Also let me say, I really appreciate the time you are putting into this. Thank you.